# In creating an ajax form using jQuery & PHP, why/how am I unable to complete the send message process?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

I am creating an ajax form using jQuery & PHP, and I am unable to complete the send message process as I am neither receiving an email or a message once submitted.  I've been working on this for some time now, researching online how to get this right, but I don't want to alter too much of the coding.  I feel as though I am missing something and I really believe it is in the jQuery file and not any of the PHP files, but I may need another eye to help point it out to me.  Below are the different components to this source code that I am having an issue with.  I need to be able to see a message (user end) once the message is submitted and I want to see that I have received an email (admin end) from the user regarding their questions, concerns or comments.

Portion of contact.php file

```
       <div id="contactform">
                                  <form id="contact" action="#">
                                    <fieldset>
                                    <span class="error" id="name_error">Please enter name !</span>
                                    <span class="error" id="email_error">Please enter email address !</span>
                                    <span class="error" id="email_error2">Please enter valid email address !</span>
                                    <span class="error" id="msg_error">Please enter message !</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="contactFormName" id="contactFormName" size="50" value="Name" class="text-input" onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Name'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Name') {this.value = ''; }" />
                                    <input type="text" name="contactFormEmail" id="contactFormEmail" size="50" value="Email" class="text-input" onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Email'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = ''; }" />
                                    <input type="text" name="contactFormSubject" id="contactFormSubject"  value="Subject" class="text-input" onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Subject'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Subject') {this.value = ''; }" />
                                    <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="contactFormMessage" id="contactFormMessage" class="text-input">Message</textarea>
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Send Message"/><br class="clear" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                  </form>
                            </div><!-- end contactform -->
.....
<!-- Form Contact Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
```

Process PHP File

```
<?php 
    $emailTo = 'email@myemail.com';
    if($contactFormSubject!=""){
    $contactFormSubject =$_REQUEST['contactFormSubject'];
    }else{
    $contactFormSubject = 'Progend Contact Form';
    }
    $contactFormName=$_REQUEST['contactFormName'];
    $contactFormEmail=$_REQUEST['contactFormEmail'];
    $contactFormMessage=$_REQUEST['contactFormMessage'];

    $body = "Name: $contactFormName \n\nEmail: $contactFormEmail \n\nMessage: $contactFormMessage";
    $headers = 'From: '.$contactFormName.' <'.$contactFormEmail.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $contactFormEmail;

    mail($emailTo, $contactFormSubject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

jQuery contact.js

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.error').hide();
  var messagetext = jQuery("textarea#msg");
  messagetext.focusout(function(){
        if (messagetext.val() == ''){messagetext.text('Message'); }
  });
  messagetext.focus(function(){
        if (messagetext.val() == 'Message') {messagetext.text(''); }                       
  });
  jQuery(".button").click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    jQuery('.error').hide();
      var name = jQuery("input#name").val();
        if (name=="Name" || name == "") {
      jQuery("span#name_error").show();
      jQuery("input#name").focus();
      return false;
    }
      var email = jQuery("input#email").val();
      if (email == "Email" || email == "") {
      jQuery("span#email_error").show();
      jQuery("input#email").focus();
      return false;
    }

    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
    jQuery("span#email_error2").show();
    jQuery("input#email").focus();
      return false;
    }

      var subject = jQuery("input#subject").val();
      if (subject == "") {
      jQuery("input#subject").focus();
      return false;
    }
      var msg = jQuery("textarea#msg").val();
      if (msg == "Message" || msg == "") {
      jQuery("span#msg_error").show();
      jQuery("textarea#msg").focus();
      return false;
    }

        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&msg=' + msg;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

      jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        jQuery('#contactform').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        jQuery('#message').html("<b>Contact Form Submitted!</b>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          jQuery('#message');
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You realize that you could strip out all the superfluous code so we have less to dig through.  It's probably safe to assume that all the jQuery animations have nothing to do with your problem, as one example.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you performed?  It would be very easy to see if you're even getting to the PHP `mail` function or not.  Then you could isolate the issue entirely to the front or back end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sparky.  This is my first time and when I was researching how to ask a question I saw that I was supposed to be very detailed.  But I can see how someone could get lost in all of the code.  I really appreciate the help.  As far as whether or not I'm even getting to the PHP.  It doesn't look as though I am. I really think the issue lies in the jQuery component.  I am doing further research; however, I felt it wouldn't hurt to ask experts.

Comment: It's important to hit the sweet-spot where you include enough relevant code without all the extraneous noise.  See http://sscce.org for tips on how to post really effective questions.  Again, you need to see if you're hitting the `mail` function.  Perhaps [use PHP to write to a log just before `mail`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) as a quickie test.  After all, until you do this simple verification, it's all just trial and error.

Comment: Ok, I will test the mail function first then.  Thanks and thanks again for the tips.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a few things wrong:

1). Since you are using ajax, take the `<input type="submit" />` and change it to `<input type="button" />` -- a submit button will try and submit the form without AJAX.

2). The ajax fires on document load. It needs to be in a click function.
(`jQuery(function() [...]` is the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function(){[...]`

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(){ [...]});
```

3).  Your success function isn't getting any response:

```
  success: function(response) {
    jQuery('#contactform').html("<div id='message'>"+response+"</div>");
```

4). Your process function isn't *sending* a response:

```
 if(mail($emailTo, $contactFormSubject, $body, $headers))
 echo "success!";
```

Comment: Your item #1 is not making a good point.  He's using a `<form>`... there's nothing at all wrong with using a `<input type="submit" />`.  He simply needs to make sure that he's properly preventing the default action.   Your solution to use a `button` instead solves nothing as the user could simply hit the `enter` key and bypass the button.

Comment: Oh, rly? good tip. Then what's the standard way of dealing with this? 
`e.preventDefault` ? `e.stopPropagation` -? Those are both button things, so I imagine the answer is 'no' - Man, I have been testing an Ajax form all day with the enter button. Please tell us how to actually handle it, then.

Comment: No, [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is not just a "button thing".   Use a `submit` handler to handle the submit action and leave the `<input type="submit" />` element where it belongs.  Meanwhile, since you cannot handle a mild critique of your answer, lose that nasty attitude.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback rm-vanda.  I will take a look at this and see how far I can get.  Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: My nasty attitude comes from experience that somehow evades your stabbing critique, @Sparky - I respect you, and I want to learn what you can offer, but I cannot continue to respect you if you cannot help me provide a better answer, especially when your critique is proven false.

Comment: Proven false?  The behavior of the `enter` key within a `form` is as per the browser.  Tested in Firefox:  http://jsfiddle.net/pTK5C/ ~  There is no button, yet hitting the `enter` key submits the `form` when focus is on the `input`.  If you want to prevent that from happening, use `preventDefault()` inside a `submit` handler.  See this version:  http://jsfiddle.net/pTK5C/1/... now hit `enter` while the `input` is focused.  Again, notice how there are no buttons on either form.  Original point: although nothing wrong with a `<button>`, it's not needed to replace the `input type="submit"` here.

Comment: Ah, see that's what I'm looking for. Its Firefox that does that - Interesting -!- I will have to go back and write that in a few places. And very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Just because I only checked Firefox doesn't mean it's isolated to Firefox.  You may want to check the various browsers' behaviors for yourself first. (_FWIW, I just confirmed that Safari is behaving exactly like Firefox._)

Comment: Interesting ! And of course--! I bet IE acts that way, also.   Very good tip. Thank you very much.